# java program becomes unresponsive

Tags: java, swing

In my speech recognition project there are two programs, one for the logic ([full program](http://pastebin.com/Fkh0cy3T)) and the other for GUI ([full program](http://pastebin.com/cg8xnfRv)).

In the GUI program I have added these lines to work with:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Start Recognizing");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        state.setText("Listening");
        System.out.println("Started Listening");
        state.setBackground(new Color(51, 204, 0));

        // Object to use from another program 
        HelloWorld obj = new HelloWorld();
        obj.main(args);
    }
});
btnNewButton.setBounds(10, 11, 156, 49);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Stop Recognizing");
btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        state.setText("Not listening");
        state.setBackground(new Color(204, 0, 51));
        System.out.println("Stopped Listening");
        // Stop the obj.main method.
    }
});
```

Now when I run the program, it displays the GUI. But when I click the start button, it becomes unresponsive and keeps on listening for speech. Even the close button of the GUI does not work. What do I do to make it responsive, and how to stop it?

Answer (score 2):

You've a classic Swing threading issue, and your solution is the same as all the others: use a SwingWorker or other background thread to do your long-running code so that it is not called o the Swing event thread. For code examples by me, please look at this [search result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a522444%20%5bswing%5d%20freeze%20body%3aswingworker). For the tutorial check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). The bottom line though is if you use the SwingWorker, the long-running code must be called from its `doInBackground()` method. No Swing calls, other than perhaps `repaint()` should be called from within that method. If after checking out the tutorial and the links you still run into trouble, then consider creating and posting in an edit to your question a minimal example program, an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small program that compiles, runs and shows your problem for us and that requires no outside libraries. If you do this, then I can show you code specific for your problem.

You've also an unrelated issue with `btnNewButton.setBounds(10, 11, 156, 49);`. You almost never want to use `null` layouts and setBounds as it leads to rigid GUI's that might look OK on one platform but terrible on all others and which is a witch to try to debug, enhance or modify. Instead you'll want to learn about and use the layout managers.

Comment: I am very new to this, can you please kindly show me how to do it.

Comment: @Robin: Please check out the links in my answer and give it a go.

Comment: @Robin: also take a look at [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6089929/522444) for a specific code example.

Comment: @Robin: if you still run into trouble, then consider creating and posting an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you do this, then I can show you code specific for your problem.

Comment: As a first pass "hack", it might be easier to simply spawn off the `HelloWorld.main()` in a new Thread than using a SwingWorker.  However, in the long run (or even the medium run) it is much better to learn about and use SwingWorker or similar.