# Repainting JPanel multiple times from an EDT

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel with some JButtons on it. When the JButtons are clicked, an event handler is invoked. Within this event handler, I would like the capability of having the JPanel repaint multiple times. There is a lot of processing that occurs in this event handler over the course of several seconds, and I need to be able to update the JPanel to display incremental updates to the user. However, when I call `repaint()` on the JPanel within the event handler, nothing seems to happen. The JPanel waits to repaint until the event handler has returned.

I have tried using the `repaint(long tm)` method, but that doesn't seem to help. How do I get this desired behavior of repainting a JPanel multiple times from within an EDT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swing is single threaded, so event handlers and painting occur on a single thread (the EDT). If you have computation that takes time and attempt to do so on the EDT, no repainting (or anything else) can be performed. To overcome this, perform the long running tasks on a separate [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) or use a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Answer (score 3):

As most all similar question answers will tell you -- use a SwingWorker to do the long-running task. Push updates to the GUI via the SwingWorker's publish/process method, and when the updates are passed into the GUI, repaint it. This way you avoid stomping on the Swing event thread and avoid freezing your program. Please check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). Also have a look at my code in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089929/522444).